# cache is not working codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, memcached

I am using the cache concept first time in codeigniter.I just followed the guidelines specified in codeigniter tutorials.But cache is not clearing after the time specified.Code is as follows:

```
$this->load->driver('cache');
if ( ! $foo = $this->cache->get('foo'))
{
 echo 'Saving to the cache!<br />';
 $foo = 'foobarbaz!';
 $this->cache->save('foo', $foo, 120);
}

echo $foo;
```

After two minutes what will be the value of $foo?
Whether i have to do any other settings?

Comment: if you can not wait for 2 min go to application/cache folder and delete cache file you will see immediate changes or new value assigned to foo.

Comment: But i am not getting the cache file in cache folder.

Comment: check your directory permission for cache folder

Answer (score 0):

```
$cache = $this->cache->get('cache_data');
if ($cache) {
   echo $data = $this->cache->get('cache_data');
} else {
   echo 'Cache is not set';
   $this->cache->save('cache_data','data',3600);
}
```

I tried this code also.But every time it will execute the else part.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! $data = $this->cache->get('cache_data'))
{
     $data = array();// your data
     $this->cache->save('cache_data', $data, 600000);
}
```